# Blazor Navigation Issue

Tags: navigation, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have 2 Blazor pages.

Home.razor @page "/"

MgrLanding.razor @page "/MgrLanding"

And one component
PersonEdit.razor

The home page has a link on it to navigate to MrgLanding page.
When I click that link it takes me to MgrLanding.

MgrLanding has the PersonEdit component.

There is a link to show the PersonEdit component.

When I clik on the link it takes me back to the Home page.

If I make the MgrLanding page the home page by: @page "/"
The behavior is as expected, the PersonEdit component shows.

**HomePage.razor**

```
@page "/"
<h3>HomePage</h3>
<a href="/MgrLanding">Mgr Landing Page</a>
```

**MgrLanding.razor**

```
@page "/MgrLanding"

<h3>MgrLanding</h3>

<a href="" onclick="@ChangeEditMode">Edit</a>

@if (EditMode)
{
    <PersonEdit Employee=@PE FormSubmittedCallback=@Save></PersonEdit>
}

@code {
    public bool EditMode { get; set; }
    public Person PE { get; set; }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        PE = new Person();
        PE.Name = "Bob The Builder";
    }
    protected void ChangeEditMode()
    {
        EditMode = true;
    }
    public void Save()
    {
        EditMode = false;
    }
}
```

**PersonEdit.razor component**

```
<h5>PersonEdit Component</h5>

<EditForm Context="formContext" Model=@Employee>
    <InputText @bind-Value=Employee.Name class="form-control" id="Name" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" @onclick="Save" />
</EditForm>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public MgrLanding.Person Employee { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback FormSubmittedCallback { get; set; }

    private void Save()
    {
        FormSubmittedCallback.InvokeAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can check here what href do: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp  That's why you have to omit the href in your example, but you still can use it for simple navigation to another component if you need to. Don't you ever set it to value(or empty which is still a value '/') and then prevent the direction - these are self-excluding actions the one is setting and the other cancelling the set :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your anchor to a button:

```
<a href="" onclick="@ChangeEditMode">Edit</a>
```

to

```
<button onclick="@ChangeEditMode">Edit</button>
```

if using an anchor for and action is **required** then a better blazor way would be simply omit the href attribute:

```
<a onclick="@ChangeEditMode">Edit</a>
```

if styling of a link is required i would

```
<button class="btn btn-link" onclick="@ChangeEditMode">Edit</button>
```

Comment: @Brian_Parker, thank you.  Can you tell me why the link does not work, but the button does?

Comment: Because Anchors are links. The Href was set to "" wich is the same as "/" so it was ignored when you had the functionality on the root page.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use link and prevent its default action

```
<a href="" @onclick:preventDefault=true 
 @onclick="@ChangeEditMode">Edit</a>
```

Comment: Asker already having link and want it to work, no idea if button can be replaced with link and serve his purpose

Comment: `You can still use link and prevent its default action.` Yes, that's true. I'll upvote your answer. `no idea if button can be replaced with link and serve his purpose.` Yes, why not. Depending on your preference, you can do that both ways.

Comment: Heres the thing about this answer. `<a onclick="@ChangeEditMode">Edit</a>` is better but it encourages bad use of html. If the appearance of a link was required "btn btn-link" class could be added to the button